# ASP.NET Core 7 app not moving past Configure method out of dev env

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, console-application

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API running with the traditional `Program` and `Startup` methods. It is running as a console application, using default settings. In Visual Studio I can run or debug and the console window opens, the server starts, and I can send requests and receive replies from port 5000/5001.

When I run the EXE outside of Visual Studio, however, I get a hung command prompt. I can't send requests to port 5000/5001 - I get `connection refused`, but if I try and run it twice, it says that those ports are not available on the second attempt.

I added some logging in the `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods, and these output to console in both instances. These methods are both logging as they complete, however the app never gets to "Listening on Port 5000" unless you run it inside Visual Studio. If I run it and attach VS to the process, it doesn't seem to be stuck anywhere.

I get no errors in EventViewer or anywhere else.

Output to console in Visual Studio:

```
info: ApiAppTesting.Startup[0]
  App Configure Completed
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
  Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
  Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Output when running the same EXE on the command prompt (either as administrator or not, or in Powershell):

```
info: ApiAppTesting.Startup[0]
  App Configure Completed
```

App hangs here.

I'm not sure how to debug this further, or what methods the inbuilt code calls next so I can further debug. I've created a blank Web API app using the same settings and this doesn't happen.

Is there something I need to change to get it to run outside the IDE, or is there extra logging I can turn on to see exactly where it freezes?

**Edit**: I ran `netstat -a` as suggested and can see that port 5000 (http) is listening. If I send a request to that port via Telnet I get the console logging a message:

> Failed to determine the https port for redirect

So I think it is something to do with `https` (using self signed dev certificate but works in Visual Studio....). Not getting any error messages still.

**Edit**: code in `Program.cs`:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Start");
        Console.ReadLine(); //Added to allow debugger to attach before anything is run
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Comment: Try using `try-catch` block in the code and print the exception message in the console. Also it is not clear what extra code you have written other than the boiler plate code of web api which might be breaking. So without seeing your code it is not possible to even guess what could be wrong with it.

Comment: Did you check whether the port is occupied from CMD with `netstat -a` when `.exe` file is running?

Comment: @Chetan I have no other code other than code for the controllers, so it's something that is running internally before any of my code is hit. Try Catch block around the Main proc contents does nothing - an exception doesn't get thrown.

Comment: @Talkhak1313 thanks, this is helpful. I actually can see it is listening on port 5000, but not port 5001 (which is https), so I think that it is something to do with the Https not able to be established (I'm using a self signed Dev cert). I'll try some different ports. Thanks

Comment: @Talkhak1313 if I try to Telnet to port I get this message logged:

Failed to determine the https port for redirect

So I think this is something to do with Https

Comment: @Molloch Can you share the code of Program.cs file?

Comment: Cool, can you check in your project properties -> Debug -> App Url if it sets to `http` or `https`?

Comment: @Molloch Also, if you are running on `IIS`, make sure `Use SSL` is ticked.